# C++, Qt 5.12.5: Q_ENUM not readable as string by Javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qmetatype

With `Qt 5.6.3` it was working, upgrading to `Qt 5.12.5` it stopped.

Javascript gets now 0 (int value of enum LogoutResult -> Success) and not 'Success' (a string).

Our class with the enum:

```cpp
namespace Modules
{
namespace Utils
{
class LogoutChecker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    enum class LogoutResult
    {
        Success,
        Installing,
        Uninstalling,
        GameRunning,
        Ignoring
    };
    Q_ENUM(LogoutResult)

    LogoutChecker(QObject* parent = nullptr);
    ~LogoutChecker() {}

    LogoutResult getLogoutRequestResult();

private:
    LogoutResult getResult(CheckType type);
};
}
}
```

Where registered:

```cpp
View::View(QObject* parent)
{
    qRegisterMetaType<Modules::Utils::LogoutChecker::LogoutResult>("LogoutResult");
    ...
}
```

Where used, called by Javascript:

```cpp
LogoutChecker::LogoutResult View::logout()
{
    const auto logoutResult = LogoutChecker().getLogoutRequestResult();

    if (logoutResult == LogoutChecker::LogoutResult::Success)
    {
        ...
    }

    return logoutResult;
}
```

If I return it converted to string:

```cpp
    return QVariant::fromValue(logoutResult).toString()
```

of course it works, but this should not be needed.

I've tried all I could think of (moving the `qRegisterMetaType` in other places, adding `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`, etc) but no way to solve it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Added the JS part:

```
  const requestSignOut = () =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      __app.logout(result => {
        if (result === 'Success') {
          resolve(result)
        } else {
          reject(result)
        }
      })
    )
```

Comment: Is `LogoutChecker` registered anywhere? I know a bit has changed "recently" in terms to how enums are handled in JS, at least in regards to QtQuick (which I think affect all JS exports). Can you provide MRE with the JS usage part (which I assume is not in QML)? I wonder if `qmlRegisterType()` would help in any case.

Comment: @Maxim I added the JS code. What is `MRE`? `LogoutChecker` should be registered using `Q_ENUM` as documented by QT. Edit: no sorry, only `LogoutResult` is registered.

Comment: It seems that it could have something to do with this bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-58454

Comment: And this:
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-63074